Dependencies problem when trying to add OpenAI's dependency
[SOLVED : see below] i don't know if someone could help me with an issue. I'm developing an application using SpringBoot, and i'm encountering an issue when i try to install OpenAI dependency. When i try to build my app, i have the following errors :
build fail
Here is my build.gradle file before trying to add OpenAI library :
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
}

group = 'be.helmo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'

    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.20.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.20.0'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.derby:derby:10.14.2.0'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

Here is my build.gradle after trying to install it :
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
}

ext {
    springAiVersion = "1.0.0-M3"
}

group = 'be.helmo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.ai:spring-ai-openai-spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'

    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.20.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.20.0'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.derby:derby:10.14.2.0'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.ai:spring-ai-bom:$springAiVersion"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

EDIT (Solved) :
I resolved everything by removing the bom thing. Here's my updated build.gradle file (i juste need to specify the API key now, to be able to use OpenAI library) :
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
}

group = 'be.helmo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.ai:spring-ai-openai-spring-boot-starter:1.0.0-M3'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'

    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.20.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.20.0'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.derby:derby:10.14.2.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

